# How to get range of ip addresses of current network

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, cidr

I am using AWS to host my website, recently I've been getting a lot of background noise on the server (bots trying to backdoor, etc.). I would like to limit access of my website to just our worksites so that other IP's cannot interact with our site. The problem is when I change the inbound rules for my security group to 'My IP' I lose the ability to connect to our server after a period of time. This isn't just for HTTP/HTTPS but is also for SSH. So I am looking to find the IP range of my current network (we work in a building owned by a large corporation and operate through their network) so I can allow connections only coming from this building.

Comment: Your best bet will be asking the network admin.

Comment: If this is really network abuse.. you would probably have it very quickly resolved via your ISP if it originates from your ISP - therefore, whitelisting *your entire ISP* (e.g. a large prefix you will find mentioned in whois for your current IP) is close enough.

Comment: @anx thank you that helped me, just tossed the IP ranges into CIDR format and it worked with the inbound rules